# Contents of uniform int[8] area always zero?

Tags: opengl

I'm building a shader program to render a simple bitmap font in GLSL.

My programming environment is C# so I'm using OpenTK to encapsulate OpenGL 4.0, but the syntax is very similar to any examples in C and C++.

My issue is that I'm trying to pass an array of integers to the fragment shader, but whenever I do, all the array elements end up being zero. The integers should range between 0 and 255 and I've checked the values before and after sending them. It's infuriating.

Currently I'm binding my program, then attempting to send the int[] array to the shader using the following instructions:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 };
GL.UseProgram(programLocation);
GL.Uniform1(arrayLocation, ints.Length, ints);
```

My fragment shader takes the array and uses a couple of functions to determine which part of the quad to place which characters. I've tested these functions with static numbers and arrays I build manually in the shader and they work just as I'd expect them to. For some reason the syntax above simply doesn't actually end up sending any data - all elements evaluate to 0.

In my shader, the array is denoted and used like this:

```
uniform int characters[8];
....
gl_FragColor = texture2D(bitmapFontTex, GetBitmapFontStart(characters[0...8etc]));
```

The rest of my code seems to work when tested in isolation - it only falls apart when it comes together, and the above code blocks are where it comes together. Have I made some silly rookie mistake, or is there something more screwy happening? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong version of `glUniform*()`
What you want to use for sending a 1D array of ints is `glUniform1iv()`.

Note how the `i` is for int, `f` for float. The number represents the number of elements.
Now for arrays suffix `v` and number represents the dimensions.

```
GL.Uniform1iv(arrayLocation, ints.Length, ints);
```

Here is a link for reference
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glUniform.xml

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't it. Uniform1iv doesn't exist in OpenTK - it's bundled into GL.Uniform1 in a method overload.

http://i.imgur.com/GFIk6OD.png

Comment: Yes you are correct, OpenTK does bundle them into `Uniform1()`. @user2312610 can you check if your arrayLocation is correct? are you using `arrayLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(programLocation, String("characters"));` Incorrect `arrayLocation` could be the cause your values are not being passed to the shader.

Comment: My Uniform addresses for the shader I'm using come up as the following.

http://i.imgur.com/dXC96lP.png

where 'characters' is the int array that I want to assign to, and the others are attributes and uniforms alike. To my knowledge this should be alright - none of them appear to be -1 so I assume they exist at least.

Thanks for taking the time by the way.

Comment: Can you add your glsl code. Its hard to spot the problem with the information given. It would be better if you could provide a MVCE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve